# How do i send an email using asp in a vb code page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i tried this:

```
        Dim mail
        mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        mail.To = consul.Email
        mail.From = "ADM@CFChamplain.ca"
        mail.Subject = subj
        mail.HTMLBody = Bdy
        mail.Send()
        mail = Nothing
```

It gave me the following error: 
The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid.

Comment: You tagged it asp.net/vb.net but the code posted is asp/vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for my applications, it's for ASP.NET.  You'll need to do an import at the top of your class for .net.mail. --> Imports System.Net.Mail

```
Public Sub SendEmail(ByVal Sentfrom As String, ByVal Recipient As String, _
                     ByVal SubjectLine As String, ByVal Messagebody As String)
```

`Dim SmtpEngine As New SmtpClient
    SmtpEngine.Host = "yourhost.com"

    Try
        SmtpEngine.Send(Sentfrom & "@taco.com", Recipient & "@taco.com", SubjectLine, Messagebody)
    Catch ex As Exception
        My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex)
    End Try

End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
Public Sub SendMsg(from, dest, subj, body)
    Dim msg, flds, conf

    Set msg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set conf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Set flds = conf.Fields

    flds(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    flds(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.xyz.org"
    flds(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25

'if use SMTP authentication...
        flds(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
        flds("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxxxxx"
        flds("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "zzzzzz"
    '... or, without SMTP authentication
        flds(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoAnonymous

    flds.Update

    On Error Resume Next
    With msg
        Set .Configuration = conf
        .BodyPart.CharSet = "utf-8"
        .TextBodyPart.CharSet = "utf-8"
        .To = dest
        .From = from
        .Subject = subj
        .TextBody = body
        .Send
    End With
    On Error Goto 0

    set msg = nothing
    set conf = nothing
    set flds = nothing
End Sub
```